# Solving a non-linear ode system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having difficulties to solve a problem, everything that I try leads to a harder problem, so if there are any tips it would help a lot.

This is the problem:

Find all non-trivial solutions $(x(t),y(t))=(\Phi(t),\Psi(t))$ (if there are such solutions) of the system

$$
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{dx}{dt}=-xy^2\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=-x^4y(y+1)
\end{array}
$$
satisfying $\underset{t\rightarrow +\infty }{\lim }(\Phi(t),\Psi(t))=(0,0)$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{cases}
 \frac{dx}{dt}=-xy^2\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=-x^4y(y+1)
\end{cases}
\quad\to\quad x^3dx=\frac{y}{y+1}dy=\left(1-\frac{1}{y+1}\right)dy$$
$$\frac{x^4}{4}=y-\ln|y+1|+c$$
Condition : $\begin{cases}t=\infty\\x=0\\y=0\end{cases} \quad\to\quad c=0 \quad\to\quad \frac{x^4}{4}=y-\ln|y+1| $

$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=-4(y+1)\left(y-\ln|y+1|\right)\\
$$
The solution is expressed on parametric form :
$$\begin{cases}
t=\int \frac{dy}{4(y+1)\left(-y+\ln|y+1|\right)}+c_1\\
x=\left(4(y-\ln|y+1|)\right)^{1/4} 
\end{cases}$$

There is no closed form for this integral. But this doesn't mean that no solution exist. In fact, many solutions exist, according to the arbirary constant $c_1$.

Note :

For $y\to 0$ one can see that $t\sim -\int \frac{dy}{2y^2}+c_1\sim \frac{1}{2y}+c_1$. Thus $t\to\infty$ as expected.